# Why is the full page background in WordPress hiding the page scroll bar?

Tags: wordpress, background-image

I am having trouble with a full page background in a test wordpress site.  I can't get the page scroll bar to appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please only answer if you have a definite answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out myself:

I changed this for the background image:

`position: absolute;`

to

```
position: fixed;
```

and deleted

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This allows the scroll bar to appear and the fixed background position makes the background stay in place.  The background still re-sizes perfectly, this just lets your content scroll.

Then add the following to do away with the horizontal scroll that appears:

```
overflow-x: hidden; /*Horizontal scrollbar*/
-ms-overflow-x: hidden; /*IE 8 horizontal scrollbar*/
```

Comment: You just made everything harder on yourself, but as long as you got what you needed.

Comment: Your answer did not work. Until you can supply me with a better answer (that at least works), lets not debate.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

The issue is you added the following to your body tag.

```
position: fixed;
```

Remove that line and everything should work then.

---

That is probably because there is no need for a scrollbar because the page doesn't extend the full height of your screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the news and contact page extend out of view, are you seeing a scrollbar?

Comment: Your CSS looks all kinds of messy, why is it that your #big-container is position:absolute; with top:0; and left: 0; ? That could be the problem.

Comment: Most of the CSS is the thematic framework.  The rest is in there as a test like I had said.  If I knew the answer I would not have posted this question.

Comment: that is what I had, there was no absolute position in the body tag.  Are you looking at something else?

Comment: No, you need to REMOVE the position:fixed; from the body tag.

Comment: Can you please do it again and then give me time to evaluate.

Comment: Ok, just removed.  Check the news page.  It has the most content.

Comment: Can you give me the structure that the content is in? Ex. body > #container > #content

Comment: I feel you have been guessing with your answers.  No offense but I want to find someone else to help.  Thank you.